# Zend ErrorHandler plugin recalling registered plugins

Tags: zend-framework, error-handling

When the errorcontroller plugin catches an error, it seems to recall my other registered plugins (after they have already been called). For example, I have a viewsetup plugin which, on `preDispatch`, sets up my application view settings (headtitle,headlink,headscript,navigation,etc.). How can I fix this so the errorplugin doesnt recall my other plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "unring the bell". By the time the `ErrorHandler` plugin kicks in at `postDispatch` and `dispatchLoopShutdown`, any plugins with `routeStartup`, `routeShutdown`, and `preDispatch` hooks have already run.

However, if you have specific needs for your views when handling the error condition - like changing the headTitle(), headScript(), layout, navigation, etc -  then you can reset them in the `ErrorController`.

Comment: I dont understand then why the errorcontroller is recalling my predispatch method within my viewsetup plugin. Clearly, the errorhandler operates on more than just postDispatch and dispatchLoopShutdown.

Comment: Aaah, I think I understand now what you mean. When an exception gets thrown and the `ErrorController::errorAction()` gets invoked, it starts a new dispatch cycle. So the `preDispatch` listeners are all notified again.